# Windows 7 laptop won't load past the Windows logo

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod

My computer won't load past the windows logo, when it finishes loading the logo I see a blue screen quickly flash on and off. I just get a glimpse of it, but I recognize the screen as a serious error message screen. After that it just shows a black screen with a movable cursor. I've tried to repair, load last good configuration, but nothing seems to work. I'm running Windows 7, it's a toshiba laptop with 4 GB SDRAM, 320 GB HDD, and an Intel Pentium T4200 processor.

Comment: What was the last change you made?

Comment: Try to take record picture/video of the error message, then search for the message online.

Comment: none, i just want to reinstall win7 i don't even care if i lose data. safe mode doesn't work either

Answer (score 3):

Use F8 at boot time to get the Windows advanced screen, then choose "Disable Automatic Restart on System Failure"

The BSOD should stay up, copy the entire message down and post it.

Or better yet, use an Ubuntu boot CD to copy All the .dmp files from the Windows\Minidump folder, zip them up and upload them to a file hosting site and post the link to them here, we can try to debug the files and possibly see what is causing the bsod.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/use-ubuntu-live-cd-to-backup-files-from-your-dead-windows-computer/